# Can't see the flash memory in file manager

Tags: flash, usb-drive, ram, format, sd-card

I've an **Ubuntu 16.04** but, i tried to copy some files onto a flash memory.
in copying time, i ***ended*** the copy operation and i disconnected this flash memory.
Now, can't see the flash memory in file manager Just can see this in the */dev* directory.
Meantime, can't use *fdisk* command.
Thenks.

Comment: You can open the Disk utility and check the status of the drive and its partition(s). It can appear as unreadable due to corruption.

Comment: Hi.
thanks for your answer, But can't see this on Disk Utility.
@CelticWarrior